# Approximate the distribution of a sum of binomial random variables in R

Tags: r, statistics, pearson

My goal is approximate the distribution of a sum of binomial variables.
I use the following paper [The Distribution of a Sum of Binomial Random Variables](http://statistics.stanford.edu/~ckirby/techreports/ONR/SOL%20ONR%20467.pdf) by Ken Butler and Michael Stephens.

I want to write an R script to find Pearson approximation to the sum of binomials.
There is an R-package  [PearsonDS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PearsonDS/index.html) that allows do this in a simple way.

So I take the first example from the paper and try to find density of the Pearson distribution for this case.
Finally i get an error message "There are no probability distributions with these moments".

Could you please explain me what's wrong in the below code?

```
library(PearsonDS)
```

# define parameters for five binomial random varibles

```
n<-rep(5,5)
p<-seq(0.02,0.10,0.02)
```

# find the first four cumulants

```
k.1<-sum(n*p)
k.2<-sum(n*p*(1-p))
k.3<-sum(n*p*(1-p)*(1-2*p))
k.4<-sum(n*p*(1-p)*(1-6*p*(1-p)))
```

# find the skewness and kurtosis parameters

```
beta.1<-k.3^2/k.2^3
beta.2<-k.4/k.2^2
```

# define the moments and calculate

```
moments <- c(mean=k.1,variance=k.2,skewness=sqrt(beta.1),kurtosis=beta.2)
dpearson(1:7,moments=moments)
```

I get the error message "There are no probability distributions with these moments".

Comment: It's not clear to me from the documentation how `dpearson` determines the distribution type when you override with `moments` . Try using The desired `dpearson[I thru VII]` function directly if you know which distribution you want to use.  Alternatively, make sure all your `moments` arguments are legal, e.g. variance>0 and real.

Comment: @Carl, thanks for the response.
I've read more carefully the documentation.

Comment: The function `pearsonFitM` determines the distribution type. The message "There are no probability distributions with these moments" is displayed when the kurtosis minus 1 is less than the skewness.
Unfortunately, I don't know and can not find the causes of this condition. If i drop it, then the cumulants define the PearsonI distribution.

Comment: sorry, i made a typo. 
The correct form of the invalid condition should be _the kurtosis minus 1 is less than the square of the skewness_

Answer (score 2):

What you try to insert as kurtosis in your moments, is actually the *excess kurtosis*, which is just `kurtosis - 3`. From the help-page of `dpearson()`:

> moments:
>   optional vector/list of mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis (not excess kurtosis).

So adding 3 to `beta.2` will provide you with the real kurtosis:

```
beta.1 <- (k.3^2)/(k.2^3)
beta.2 <- k.4/(k.2^2)
kurt <- beta.2 + 3

moments <- c(mean = k.1, variance = k.2, skewness = beta.1, kurtosis = kurt)
dpearson(1:7, moments=moments)
# [1] 0.3438773545 0.2788412385 0.1295129534 0.0411140817 0.0099279576
# [6] 0.0019551512 0.0003294087
```

To get a result like the one in the paper, we should investigate the cumulative distribution function and add 0.5 to correct for the bias caused by approximating a discrete distribution by a continuous one:

```
ppearson(1:7+0.5, moments = moments)
# [1] 0.5348017 0.8104394 0.9430092 0.9865434 0.9973715 0.9995578 0.9999339
```

## A little background information:

The function threw an error because the relationship between kurtosis and skewness wasn't invalid: kurtosis is lower-bounded by the skewness in the following way: `kurtosis >= (skewness)^2 - 1`. The proof ain't pretty and is certainly beyond the scope of the question, but you can check out the references below if you like for different versions of this inequality.

1. **Wilkins, J. Ernest**. A Note on Skewness and Kurtosis. Ann. Math. Statist. 15 (1944), no. 3, 333--335. http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177731243.
2. **K. Pearson**. Mathematical contributions to the theory of evolution, XIX; second supplement to a memoir on skew variation. Philos. Trans. Roy. Soc. London Ser. A, 216 (1916), p. 432 http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/216/538-548/429
3. **Pearson, K.** (1929). "Editorial note to 'Inequalities for moments of frequency functions and for various statistical constants'". Biometrika. 21 (1–4): 361–375. [link](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-lookup/doi/10.1093/biomet/21.1-4.361)

Comment: The numbers don't seem to match up with the numbers for the Pearson approximation in table 3. Could you comment on that?